# How to pass omitted argument to the next function?

Tags: matlab

In matlab I can omit arguments of a function, for example

```
function res = caller(a, b)
...
```

I can call it with

```
caller(12)
```

But how can I pass this absent argument further, for example:

```
function res = caller(a, b)
   callee(a, b)
   ...
```

How can I make that if `caller` is called without secong argument, then `callee` also called without second argument?

**UPDATE**

Suppose you have many functions calling each other

```
function res = caller01(a, b)
    ...

function res = caller02(a, b)
    ...

function res = caller03(a, b)
    ...

function res = caller04(a, b)
    ...
```

and you want to

1) make argument `b` optional

2) make it possible to delegate default to callee

As far as I understood, Matlab is incomplete here and requires me to wrap each call to callee into this scaffold:

```
if exist('b', 'var')
   callee(a, b);
else
   callee(a);
end
```

and this should be repeated in each caller.

Comment: you can not do what you mean unless `b` is `varargin` or you have a `nargin` check inside. If that is the case, then you also have a default value for `b` inside. Therefore the problem you propose does not exist, right? Or I am missing something?

Comment: @AnderBiguri you are missing something

Comment: @AnderBiguri `varargin` is separate feature; here we are regarding feature which makes us able to omit some explicit arguments. In the caller, I can have defaults in one branches of code or can delegate them to callees.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different options here.

**Option 1**

```
function res = caller(varargin)
   callee(varargin{:})
   ...
```

Here we capture all input arguments in `varargin`, and pass them unchecked to `callee`.

**Option 2**

```
function res = caller(a, b)
   if nargin == 0
      callee()
   elseif nargin == 1
      callee(a)
   else if nargin == 2
      callee(a, b)
   end
   ...
```

Here we check the number of input arguments, and call `callee` with the arguments we were given.

**Option 3**

```
function res = caller(a, b)
   if nargin<1
      a = rand(10);
   end
   if nargin<2
      b = 'default value';
   end
   callee(a, b)
   ...
```

Here we check input arguments, and use default values for non-specified input arguments.

---

**Edit:** It is possible to do a hybrid here also. Say `a` is a required argument, and `b` is an optional one. We let MATLAB handle the required argument (it automatically generates the appropriate error messages when not provided), and put `b` into `varargin`, which we can use to call `callee` with the same number of input arguments we got, and also unpack to generate the local variables we need for further processing:

```
function res = caller(a,varargin)
   callee(a,varargin{:})
   if numel(varargin)>=1
      b = varargin{1};
   end
   ...
```

Comment: Option #2 is what I need. But I will rewrite the code deeper and deeper, if I need to pass calls further. So, Matlab syntax is incomplete here...

Comment: @Dims: See the edit. I think that could simplify your code structure if you need to pass an undefined number of arguments across many functions. The `nargin` check you need to do anyway if you plan to use `b` later, no? This wouldn't add any complexity, I think.

Answer (score 0):

I usually do a simple 'if block', to my knowledge this is unavoidable if you want to preserve your `caller(a,b)` function in the form provided.

Something flexible I use often:

```
function res = caller(a, b)
  if exist('b','var')
    callee(a,b)
  else
    callee(a)
  end
end
```

alternatively you can use `varargin` and 'pipe' whatever arguments came in, directly into `callee` as already mentioned by Cris, and handle whatever varargin is within callee.

```
function res = caller(varargin)
  callee(varargin{:})
end
```

Comment: This will require to reqwrite the code if `callee` calls something else in turn.

Comment: what do you mean?